# JQuery Function is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am doing an application in ASP.Net using C#. Also in my application I am using jquery for some client side operation in a separate .js file. Some of the client methods are written in separate .js and file some of written in .aspx page itself.
My application is running properly in Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome but I am getting an error when I am trying to execute the application in Internet Explorer. I am using IE 11.
The error is like
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'add_resize_dragdrop' is undefined

The said method written in separate .js file. There are another method which is written in .aspx file. I am not getting the error for that method.
Please help me out from here.

Comment: Is your separate file loading?

Comment: @Satpal Yes.. Some of JQuery function written in separate .js file and some of them written in .aspx file.

Comment: Can you post your code? e.g function code and part where you calling this function.

Comment: Do you using `$(document).ready()` to call your function? Its looking like in IE .js file is not loaded when you try to use your function.

Comment: @Wado JQuery "contains" function not supported by IE. I am getting this error.